# How to catch google chrome audit lighthouse

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

How can I catch in Javascript a user running an Audit from Lighthouse in my website?

I'd like to see if there is a possibility, out of curiosity.

**Edit:**

Based on @DBS answer, I'd like to see that If I can catch it during the process

```
    <script>
        if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome-Lighthouse") > -1) {
            document.body.innerHTML = "Lighthouse!";
        } else {
            document.body.innerHTML = "No lighthouse :("
        }
    </script>
```

[image]

Comment: As far as i know there isn't any possibility.

Answer (score 4):

If by "catch", you simply mean detect it. The Lighthouse process includes a custom user agent.

Searching the user agent for the string `Chrome-Lighthouse`

e.g.

```js
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome-Lighthouse") > -1) {
  console.log("Lighthouse!");
} else {
  console.log("No lighthouse :(")
}
```

I don't believe it's possible to "catch" in the debugging sense of interacting with the process.

Comment: Yeah I imagine, it would be great if it was possible actually. As you can see in the edit

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to catch it from the User agent.
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3694.0 Mobile Safari/537.36 Chrome-Lighthouse

From [Source Code](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/search?q=Chrome-Lighthouse&unscoped_q=Chrome-Lighthouse)